# Get Mysql Join Table Data into Sub Array

Tags: php, mysql, json

Table : new_parent_join

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id  |   child_id    |   user_id     |   other_email             |   token                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   5   |   3           |   1           |   mento.holm@mail.com     |   c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table : user_child_data

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   id  |   user_id     |   child_name  |   child_surname   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |   1           |   Jack        |   Holm            |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table : users_data

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id  |   user_name   |   user_surename   |   email               |   relation    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   Mento       |   Holm            |   mentoholm@mail.com  |   father      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Mysql query looks

```
SELECT 
        npj.*, 
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'id', ucd.id, 
            'user_id', ucd.user_id, 
            'child_name', ucd.child_name, 
            'child_surename', ucd.child_surename 
        ) as userChildData, 
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'id', ud.id, 
            'user_name', ud.user_name, 
            'user_surename', ud.user_surename, 
            'email', ud.email, 
            'relation', ud.relation 
        ) as usersData 
        FROM new_parent_join npj 
        JOIN user_child_data ucd on npj.child_id = ucd.id 
        JOIN users_data ud on npj.user_id = ud.id 
        WHERE npg.token = 'c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39' 
        LIMIT 1
```

And Output is :

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "child_id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "other_email": "mento.holm@mail.com",
    "token": "c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39",
    "userChildData":
    {
        "id":3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "child_name": "Jack",
        "child_surename":"Holm"
    },
    "usersData":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_name": "mento",
        "user_surename":"Holm",
        "email":"mentoholm@mail.com",
        "relation":"father"
    }
}
```

I want to get all fields of that join table like userdata.* i dont like to type one by one key value in json_object